# How to position two elements in <label> side by side

Tags: html, label

[image: I want the "SSSS" to be on the right side of the "XXXXXX" text]

```html
<label for="checkbox6">XXXXXX
     <div style="padding-left: 9.5%;padding-right: 45%;padding-bottom:1.5%"><input class="form-control" name="quantum" type="number" min="1" placeholder="SSSS" required></div>
     </label>
```

I want the "SSSS" to be on the right side of the "XXXXXX" text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display:flex` to `<label>` like so:

```
label {
  display: flex;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5pyhg7aw/)

Also note I removed the original padding styles u provided in ur code.

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your snippet:

- Do not nest your input inside the label.
- Your `for` attribute does not match the `input` element's `name` attribute.

```html
<div>
    <label for="myInput">XXXXX</label>
    <input name="myInput" placeholder="SSSS"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
<label for="checkbox6">XXXXXX</label>
<input class="form-control" name="quantum" type="number" min="1" placeholder="SSSS" required>
</div>
```